# XOR of two numbers AND third number ?

Tags: boolean-algebra

If:

> x & (a ^ b) != 0

Then one of the following holds:

> x & a == 0; x & b != 0

or

> x & b == 0; x & a != 0

What is the reason for this? And are there similar properties of AND/OR/NOT with XOR?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not true. Take for example $x=3, a=1, b=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at the problem from another angle, a pure algebraic one.

Let $a,b,x$ be boolean variables taking values either $T$ or $F$ and $\alpha,\beta,\chi$ be numbers
in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the equivalent classes of integers modulus 2, taking values
either $1$ or $0 \pmod 2$.

If you look at the truth table for $a, b$ under logical AND/XOR operations
and the multiplication/addition tables for $\alpha, \beta$ side by side,

$$\begin{array}{r|ll}
a \text{ & } b  & T & F\\
\hline
T & T & F\\
F & F & F\\
\end{array}
\;vs.\;
\begin{array}{r|ll}
\alpha \text{ * } \beta  & 1 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\quad\text{ AND }\quad
\begin{array}{r|ll}
a \text{ ^ } b  & T & F\\
\hline
T & F & T\\
F & T & F\\
\end{array}
\;vs.\;
\begin{array}{r|ll}
\alpha \text{ + } \beta & 1 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
$$

You will find they are identical. In other words, the algebra generated by the
logical AND and XOR operations is isomorphic to the algebra of multiplication/addition of integers under modulus $2$.

We know addition and multiplication of integers satisfy distributive law. 
So does the logical AND and XOR operation. i.e

$$\chi*(\alpha+\beta) = \chi*\alpha + \chi*\beta \quad vs. \quad
  x \text{ & } (a \text{ ^ } b ) = ( x \text{ & } a ) \text{ ^ } (x \text{ & } b)$$

Recall given any two boolean expression $u$ and $v$,

$$u \text{ ^ } v = T 
\quad\text{ iff }\quad 
u \ne v
\quad\text{ iff }\quad
( u = T \text{ AND }  v = F ) \text{ OR } ( u = F \text{ AND } v = T ).
$$
We can transform the given logical condition as follows
$$\begin{align}
& x \text{ & } (a \text{ ^ } b) = T\\
\iff & ( x \text{ & } a ) \text{ ^ } ( x \text{ & } b ) = T\\
\iff & ( x \text{ & } a ) \ne ( x \text { & } b )\\
\iff &
\bbox[4pt,border:1px solid]{ 
\begin{array}{rrcl}
            & (( x \text{ & } a ) = T & \text{ AND } & (x \text{ & } b) = F)\\
\text{ OR } & (( x \text{ & } a ) = F & \text{ AND } & (x \text{ & } b) = T)
\end{array}}
\end{align}$$

What you see is nothing special, but a consequence of the distributive law between the logical AND and XOR operation.

Answer (score 1):

`x & (a^b) != 0`

`x & (a^b) == 1`

`x==1; a^b==1`

For `a^b==1` to hold, either `a==0;b==1` must hold or `a==1;b==0` must hold (i.e., `a!=b`). Doing the `&` operations with `a` gives you the two cases that you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that x is true, because our 'and' is evaluating to true. The xor has to evaluate to true as well, so we also require that a and b are different.

What does this imply?

To answer your further question. If an xor is only true if a and b are different then xnor is only true if a and b are the same.

There is nothing particularly interesting about an or with an xor.